# SQL SELECT skip first N results?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my query:

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE MATCH (City) AGAINST ('$city') ORDER by Date DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Basically I want to skip the first 10 results and only select result N: `$page * 10` to show the results that correspond to that page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the OFFSET keyword

```
$offset = $page*10;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE MATCH (City) AGAINST ('$city') ORDER by Date DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET '$offset'");
```

Answer (score 4):

Check the keyword OFFSET :

`... LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Limit 10,10
```

Where the first 10 is the offset and the second 10 is how many rows you want to retrieve after the offset