# Select after first 50 with MYSQL and PHP

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select all the `rows` AFTER the first 50 rows from a `table`. I can't seem to figure out an efficient way to do it.

I could select the first 50 `rows`, put their `IDs` in an array, then make another `query` that selects everything except them, but that seems wasteful.

I can't seem to find anything here that does what I need:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Is there anyway to do this in one `SQL query`? Thanks for the help!

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: `OFFSET` of 50 ordered by primary key `ASC`?

Comment: [StackOverflow: Skip first _n_ results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921315/sql-select-skip-first-n-results)

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably looking for `OFFSET`:

For example:

```
  SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id LIMIT 100 OFFSET 50
```

Comment: This is not valid in MySQL, you need to specify a `LIMIT`

Answer (score 2):

You can [define](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) an offset:

> [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]

Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT 5, 10; # Retrieve rows 6-15
```

Answer (score 0):

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE displayDataFromGivenRow(IN from_Id INT)

BEGIN
    DECLARE row_count INT;

```
SELECT count(*) INTO row_count
FROM <table_name>;

SELECT * 
FROM <table_name>
LIMIT row_count
OFFSET from_Id;
```

END//

DELIMITER ;

CALL displayDataFromGivenRow(50);

OR

SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT total_number_of_records OFFSET 50;

Answer (score -1):

Try this
 select * from tablename limit 50,100000000 
 the second argument in limit  you can set based on number of row your table may have